# BX slider inside tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using BX slider inside of some tabs to show and hide some products on my WooCommerce site but there seems to be an issue with the hiding and showing. I have some simple tabs to show and hide each slider here:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="tabs-container sub_sliders_controls">

        <ul class="tabs-menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Living</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2">Bedroom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-3">Dining</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-4">Sofas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-5">Office</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

Here are the tabs with a slider inside:

```
<div class="tab">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
        <div class="sub_sliders">
            <div class="bxslider2">
                <?php $wcatTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'parent' => 11, )); 
                    foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
                    $wthumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $wcatTerm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                    $wimage = wp_get_attachment_url( $wthumbnail_id );
                ?>
                <div class="slide_top_slide">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>">
                        <?php if($wimage!=""):?><img src="<?php echo $wimage?>" class="aligncenter"><?php endif;?>
                    </a>
                    <a class="slide_top_slide_link"  href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>">
                        <?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>   
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
        <div class="sub_sliders">
            <div class="bxslider2">
                <?php  
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'bedroom' ); 
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                global $product; 
                ?>  
                <?php echo '<div class="slide_main">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</div>'; ?>
                <?php
                endwhile; 
                wp_reset_query(); 
                ?>   
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        <div class="sub_sliders">
            <div class="bxslider2">
                <?php $wcatTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'parent' => 95, )); 
                    foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
                    $wthumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $wcatTerm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                    $wimage = wp_get_attachment_url( $wthumbnail_id );
                ?>
                <div class="slide_top_slide">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>">
                        <?php if($wimage!=""):?><img src="<?php echo $wimage?>" class="aligncenter"><?php endif;?>
                    </a>
                    <a class="slide_top_slide_link"  href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>">
                        <?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>   
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
        <div class="sub_sliders">
            <div class="bxslider2">
                <?php  
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'sofas' ); 
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                global $product; 
                ?>  
                <?php echo '<div class="slide_main">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</div>'; ?>
                <?php
                endwhile; 
                wp_reset_query(); 
                ?>   
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">
        <div class="sub_sliders">
            <div class="bxslider2">
                <?php  
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'office' ); 
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                global $product; 
                ?>  
                <?php echo '<div class="slide_main">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</div>'; ?>
                <?php
                endwhile; 
                wp_reset_query(); 
                ?>   
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>        
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.tabs-menu {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.tabs-menu{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.tabs-menu ul{
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tabs-menu li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tabs-menu li.current {
    color: #fc5c5c;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tabs-menu li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.tabs-menu .current a {
    color: #fc5c5c;
    border-bottom:  2px solid #fc5c5c;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.tab {
    width: 100%;
}

.tab-content {
    display: none;
}

#tab-1 {
 display: block;   
}
```

But what happens is every time I switch between the tabs it only loads the slider in tab 1 and hides the rest?

Here is the BX slider code:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 5000,
    minSlides: 4,
    maxSlides: 4,
    pager: false,
    slideMargin: 25
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you have bxSlider script?  I don't see it, but I assume your intention is to initialize on the `.bxslider2` elements. If so, bxSlider will collect it's direct children elements by default. That means that each of your bxSliders only has one slide. But this is merely conjecture since I don't see any bxSlider code.

Comment: Hey the BXSlider code is loaded in as per instrctions. the slider itself works perfectly ok, it is just when you switch between the tabs is when it does not load see here under selected products http://dev4.activeinternetdevelopment.co.uk/ also see my updated question at the botom

Comment: The instructions do not cover your situation I believe. That's a different slider for each tab? Then I can help with that.

Comment: @zer00ne So essentially I have the tabs which should show bxslider2 in each of the tab content - however it only loads the first one - there are no javascript errors in the console, I tried creating a new bxslider for each tabs but it does the same?

Comment: You need to make each one unique and initiate each one individually. So make: `.bxslider1`,`.bxslider2`, etc.

Comment: I actually fixed it with CSS - it would appear that each time the tab is fired it reset the viewport on the bxslider back to 0 and also on the slides themselves also. In my CSS I overrode the styles and it now works.

Comment: I had trouble like that after the last Chrome update, so I made bx-viewport min-height of `90vh` and then removed the inline style of height on bx-viewport as well. Upped for your design, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch up the remove and addClass:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Edit: Realized now, that this code does the same as his, I confused the .siblings() part and thought the removeClass would just remove the .current of all parent elements

Comment: Thank you offering a repair but it still does the same thing - check out http://dev4.activeinternetdevelopment.co.uk/ and the section under 'SELECTED PRODUCTS' and you will see the behaviour

Comment: Seems to work for me! When I click tab 2, the tab 1 content fades out and the tab 2 content fades in. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hey man I managed to fix it, but thanks for suggesting a fix, it would have helped in any case what you did so I will accept it :)